# ASPX page loaded to jQuery modal redirects when aspbutton click event happens

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following modal,

```
        $('#Main_Content_ClosePnl_ConfirmBtn').click(function () {

            $.get("CustomerFeedback.aspx", function (html) {
                var mydiv = $('#jQuerypopup');
                mydiv.html(html);

                //mydiv.dialog({ autoOpen: false });
                mydiv.dialog({
                    maxWidth: 600,
                    maxHeight: 500,
                    width: 600,
                    height: 500,
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    open: function (event, ui) {
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog | ui).hide();
                        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
                    }
                }
                );
            });
```

So you can see it calls in my ASPX page. Which consists of a number of aspbuttons like this;

```
<div id="Star1-Div">

<asp:ImageButton ID="Star1a" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../Images/Star(3).png" onclick="Star1a_Click;" onmouseover="this.src= '../../Images/Star(4).png'" onmouseout="this.src= '../../Images/Star(3).png'" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="Star1b" runat="server" ImageUrl="../../Images/Star(4).png" onclick ="Star1b_Click"/>
</div>
```

The click event looks like this;

```
    protected void Star1a_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Star1b.Visible = true;
        StarResult.Value = "1";
    }
```

When this click event takes place, what should happen is an image should be made visible (works) but what also happens as an adverse side effect is the modal is broken and the ASPX page is loaded into the current browser window.

I need everything to happen inside the modal popup, but cant seem to stop the redirect.

Have seen things on here about postbacks and such, tried as many examples as I can find, it would be ever so helpful if someone could slot in some code which will force the image to refresh WITHOUT reloading the page and breaking out of the modal popup please?

Comment: By default any kind of server-side button is going to invoke a post-back.  If all of the functionality you want is in client-side code, why use `asp:ImageButton` controls at all?  Why not just use regular HTML, which wouldn't post back to the server?

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back so quickly, The click event needs to set a rating (1-5) for the feedback system which will be passed to a stored procedure in a sql database

Comment: So you *do* want some kind of server-side interaction?  In order to do that without reloading the page, the technology you're looking for is called AJAX.  There are many examples and tutorials available online, but in general "How do I do AJAX" is a bit too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.  There are multiple ways to go about accomplishing it.

Comment: So there is no way to do this in c#? I'm needing to integrate with an existing system and learning a new technology isn't going to be achievable within the time constraints, this should be the final piece of the puzzle

Comment: The tools are available in ASP.NET.  There are AJAX-based controls you can use, or you can simply write some JavaScript code to accomplish the task.  But if you're *entirely* unfamiliar with the concept then, yes, you'd have to learn a little bit about it.